# Surgery and Curvature on Foliation

Tags: riemannian-geometry, 4-manifolds, foliations, curvature, surgery-theory

Let $X$ be an oriented closed smooth $4$-manifold. Suppose that $TM$ admits a foliation $\mathcal F$ of dimension two, and admits a positvescalar curvature.

**Q**: If we do the surgery on $X$ to reduce the $b_1$, would the surgery affect the positivity of the scalar curvature on $\mathcal F$.

Comment: What do you mean by positivity of scalar curvature on $\mathcal{F}$?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese scalar curvature of $\mathcal F$ is positive. I mean after the surgery the scalar curvature of $\mathcal F$ is still positive or not.